# Is it right to close a question as a combination of duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

If you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48274795/converting-milliseconds-to-date-time-formatyy-mm-dd-in-from-pandas-dataframe), it becomes a two well-known questions in one after editing when closed as a duplicate. Am I right closing it as a combination of duplicates or should this not be closed, but answered?

Comment: "Too broad" vs. "Two duplicates"... One is slow and useless, another frequently instant and providing info to OP... My bet is on "two duplicates", but I'd like to know community opinion on it too.

Comment: Doing so is perfectly acceptable when the user for example asks about the utter basics of a language feature, and the correct answer is really "go read that chapter in your book".

Comment: funny as I just did that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314664/convert-list-of-list-to-list-of-dict-in-python and was wondering the same :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

TLDR; you did the right thing.

---

If one answer asks

> How do I do `(a + b) * (c + d)`?

And you have two other questions, one showing you how to do `a + b`, and another showing you how to do `x * y`, I'd say it's safe to close the first as a duplicate of the other two, rather than fragmenting the knowledge base across multiple questions.

Furthermore, we're here to help users with their problems, as long as those users have demonstrated sincere research and effort to solve their problem, first. This question in particular, has been asked numerous times in the past (being a common pandas problem, working with datetimes), so I'm willing to bet that there are *other* equally worthy questions to mark this as a duplicate of.

If not, vote to close as "too broad", demonstrating no research effort whatsoever. Broken code does NOT count as "research", because it only means OP half-heartedly tried something which didn't work, and ended up coming to SO to have someone else solve their problem for them, which just isn't done.

So, in summary, you've put your gold badge to good use. Nicely done.

As a side note, "what if a question is answered by 3 other questions?" In that case, I'd recommend voting to close as too broad, because users should not be asking that many questions in a single post. Each post should be self-contained, and must focus on one particular issue at a time.

Comment: The problem in this example is that one might not know how the parenthesis work, so they wouldn't be able to combine the two answers.

Comment: @user000001 You'd clarify that in a comment. That's a triviality, and not something I'd keep the question open for.

Comment: I find myself doing that _very_ often. Close questions as a duplicate, and, in the comments, help OP _massage_ the dupe target's answer into their own. Works (almost) every time :)

Comment: yes a clarifying comment would be helpful in these cases

Comment: At some point there's a threshold where the explanation-in-comments becomes worthy of being an answer.  When it putting together the pieces from 3 or more questions, or multiple comments, I sometimes end up re-opening questions I've dup-hammered, and posting my comments as an answer (which links to the other questions), once I realize it's taking more explanation than I planned.  But mostly I only do this if the question is also interesting and non trivial.

Comment: I would find another question along the lines of "How do parenthesis work in X?" to add to the duplicate list

Comment: @TinyGiant you could nitpick the specific example all you like, but the truth is that it depends, and it's something you'd have to handle on a case-by-case basis. Sometimes a comment is required, sometimes another duplicate is required. Sometimes the question is so poor, it isn't worth doing anything else beyond closing.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, otherwise you fall into the "everything is a duplicate" obsession.

Comment: I miss the times where duplicates means "all possible answers to A and B are identical".